# Вопрос по лицензии GPL 2+

Tags: opensource, лицензирование

Хочу инструкцию. Пошаговую и однозначную :)

Локально возникла дискуссия, но все пришли к тому, что неоднозначно понимают GPL.

Итого, сухая выжимка. Есть [утилита](https://github.com/deanproxy/eMail), которая распространяется по GPL. На её базе делалась библиотека, исключительно для личного употребления. Если захочется выложить эту библиотеку публично, что делать?

Синопсис: некоторые файлы были оставлены без изменений, некоторые модифицированы (часть - почти до неузнаваемости, разве что на уровне прототипов функций что-то осталось), добавлены другие.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно тоже распространять под GPL версии 2+. Коротко по шагам:

- В каждом файле разместить требуемую лицензией шапку.
- Не забыть в шапке также указать всех владельцев авторских прав.
- К библиотеке приложить текст лицензии.

Полезные ссылки:

- [Как применять лицензии GNU со своими программами](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html)
- [Лицензия для вашего open-source проекта](http://habrahabr.ru/post/243091/)
- [Практическое руководство по соответствию GPL](https://www.linux.org.ru/news/opensource/11023276)
- [Ответы на вопросы о лицензиях GNU](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.ru.html)
- [GNU GPL 3 человеческим языком](http://servicesaitov.blogspot.ru/2012/01/gnu-gpl-3.html)
- [Мир лицензий: разбираемся с GNU GPL](http://megamozg.ru/post/9044/)
- Как GPLv3 совмещается с другими GNU лицензиями => http://копилефт.рф/лицензии/гну-гпл/совместимость-гну-лицензий (*увы, ссылка на такой адрес не создается*)

Comment: Вот тут вопрос. См, например, [здесь](https://github.com/deanproxy/eMail/blob/master/src/mimeutils.c): этот файл покорёжен сильно. Что делать с авторской шапкой?

Comment: @klopp Из авторской шапки Вам необходимо сохранить `Copyright © 2001 - 2008 by Dean Jones`. На следующей строке дописать `Copyright © XXXX - YYYY <Ваше имя>`  Еще нужно "сохранить" (то есть, взять шаблон и сделать свой) кусок текста, требуемый лицензией. Если что-то еще хочется добавить - можно добавить до или после. Вообще, все это по первой ссылке довольно подробно расписано.

Comment: Ну да. Для меня очевидно, что нужно сохранить оригинальное авторство. Само собой. Но что делать с файлами, которые были "изменены до неузнаваемости"? Или добавлены как новые?

Comment: P.S. А вообще, моя личная лицензия для выложеных исходников выглядит так: "Любой человек, или не человек, независимо от пола, вероисповедания, или каких-то взглядов, волен делать с этими исходниками что угодно."

Comment: @klopp Если  исходнике есть код оригинального автора (даже если это пара-тройка строк), то его копирайт обязательно остается. Можете в таком случае написать свой копирайт на строчку выше, а не ниже =) А если файл полностью написан Вами, то Вы пишете только свой копирайт. Насчет "изменены до неузнаваемости", в таких случаях лучше перестраховаться и оставить чужой копирайт (Вы ведь все равно выкладываете публично). В случае каких-то судебных претензий для таких ситуаций привлекаются эксперты, так как точных критериев тут нет.

Comment: @klopp С "личными" лицензиями нужно быть осторожнее, они могут не иметь юридической силы, иметь юридическую силу не во всех странах, иметь совсем не ту юридическую силу, которая подразумевалась, не иметь защиты от претензий пользователей и т.п. Почитайте статью по второй ссылке, я в ней как раз упоминаю про подобные тонкости для WTFPL, Beerware и Unlicense. Вместо Вашей личной лицензии лучше использовать MIT License (она же X11, она же Expat). Смысл у нее примерно такой же, но явно прописано, что разрешено, а так же есть отказ от ответственности.

Comment: Ну не нужно же доводить до  абсурда. Какой нахрен "оригинальный код", если у него там стандарт C тыщелетней давности, а я немного поправил :) И переправил нафиг. И т.д. Не на каждой строке же писать: а вот тут я это по, см ревизию тыщдевятьсот11 в svn по url... Впрочем, я тоже идиот: самое очевидное решение "спросить у автора" подумалось только сейчас.

Comment: @klopp Вам не нужно описывать все изменения. Вы пишете только авторов файла. А принадлежит им две строчки в файле или 100500 - не суть важно. Под строчками, если что, я понимаю код, а не пустые строки, скобки и отступы. А спросить у автора - идея хорошая.